# Ruby capybara autotests. It is not possible to click on certain button due that they all have same css

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, capybara

Page has multiple buttons.
I need to click first one, but they all have same class
`one-employee__remove-btn`

I could try xpath, but this kinda looks scary
`/div[contains(@class,'one-employee__user')]/div/div/p[contains(.,'#{email}')]//div[contains(@class,'one-employee__user')]/div/div/p[contains(.,'terry@lind.co')]/../../../div[contains(@class, 'one-employee__remove-btn-cont')]/button`

is there a possibility to make it happen using css?
full html for element
`<button data-v-6454fca6="" title="Fjern" class="one-employee__remove-btn"></button>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that it's always the first button you want to click, and assuming no other buttons on that page have the `one-employee__remove-btn` class you can try something like

```
all(".one-employee__remove-btn").first.click
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara supports `first(".one-employee__remove-btn").click`